# Сложный запрос к MySQL в проекте на Yii2, используя ORM ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, yii2, activerecord

Есть череда связанных запросов:

```sql
SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU';
SET @interval := DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()) + 1, '-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), CURDATE());
WITH DATESHIFT AS (
    SELECT `id`, `username`, ADDDATE(`birthday`,  @interval) birthday, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2222-', MONTH(`birthday`), '-', DAY(`birthday`)), '%Y-%m-%d')  tmpdate 
    FROM `user` 
    ORDER BY tmpdate DESC LIMIT 3), 
B_DATES AS (
    SELECT `username`, date_format(`birthday`, '%d-%m-%Y') bdate, CONCAT(DAY(`birthday`), ' ', MONTHNAME(`birthday`)) birth_string, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2222-', MONTH(`birthday`), '-', DAY(`birthday`)), '%Y-%m-%d') tmpdate 
    FROM user 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT `id` FROM DATESHIFT) 
    ORDER BY tmpdate)
SELECT `username`, `birth_string` FROM B_DATES;
```

Задача: обернуть их в конструктор ActiveRecord, либо ActiveQuery с тем, чтобы обеспечить переносимость.
В документации сообщества подобные возможности не описываются. Как работать без костылей с конструктом CTE - не понятно.
Уважаемые коллеги, прошу помощи. Спасибо!

Comment: По мне, так проще сделать хранимую процедуру или функцию и вызвать её с параметрами. Зачем пытаться извратиться с AR? AR, как по мне, вообще помойка, которая подходит разве что для простых запросов, на которых голова не ломается

Comment: Я и думал о хранимой. Но это усложнит процесс деплоя при переносе проекта. Тем более для групповой разработке.

Comment: Чем он усложняет? Написать миграцию сложнее, чем пытаться впихнуть непихуемое? ))

Comment: Миграция - это конечно было бы круто. Но вы, неверное, не до конца поняли что мне нужно. Миграции предполагают статичное действие (создание, удаление таблиц, столбцов, добавление индексов, изменение типов и т.п.). Мне же нужно получать и модифицировать данные из существующей таблицы динамически, по пользовательскому запросу.

Comment: Какой-то скрипт повышенной степени извращённости - прям попытка насоздавать себе сложностей, дабы потом их мужественно преодолеть... нафига тут локальный формат даты? нафига выбор в подзапросе полей, которые потом не используются? что за непонятные верчения дат? да, 2222 год тоже порадовал. В общем, типичная https://xyproblem.info/ Формулируйте задачу, которую надо решить, и исходный материал для её решения. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169), особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: *Миграции предполагают статичное действие (создание, удаление таблиц, столбцов, добавление индексов, изменение типов и т.п.).* Создание хранимой процедуры - тоже статическое действие. А уже внутри неё статический код может использовать динамический SQL (правда, я в упор не вижу, нафига он тут нужен).

Comment: "Миграции предполагают статичное действие"........"по пользовательскому запросу" ........... - миграция тут нужна для того, чтобы создать функцию в бд с параметрами........далее пользователь вводит что ему там надо, эти данные отправляются в функцию с параметрами (что логично), которая будет отдавать по этим самым параметрам данные. Никаких проблема с этим не вижу

Comment: Алексей, отлично! Спасибо!

Comment: Akina, спасибо дяденька за науку и за ответы на вопросы, которых я не задавал. )) Отдельное и искреннее спасибо за то, что форматировали мой код.

Comment: Алексей, прошу прощения. Что-то я ни каких доках не нашёл упоминания о том, что через миграцию можно создать функцию.

Comment: Упомянуть кого-то в комментариях можно через собачку.... Типа такого @МихаилСтекачёв   .... не нашли потому, что вы привыкли к AR, которым наверняка и в миграциях тоже пользуетесь.... Однако помимо этого есть ещё и обычные запросы.. DAO например. Или вообще чистым pdo. Мы например в компании давно отошли от запросов в миграциях через builder... потому что, как я уже писал выше, слишком долго писать, слишком сложно его понимать, а когда запрос не маленький - то это превращается в непонятное сложное месиво.....  тут пример как писать миграцию https://pastein.ru/t/2aH

Comment: А как сами процедуры или функции делать - это к документации БД

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , спасибо! Вы очень помогли!